# python key value pairing

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have one array like this `arr1 = ['name','age','sex']` and another array that has values of this array like `val1 = ['Jone','20','male']` . Now I want to make a dict that will look like this --> `val = {'name':'jone','age':'20','sex':'male'}`

current I am doing that dict this way -->

```
val = {}
val['name'] = val1[0]
val['age'] = val1[1]
val['sex'] = val1[2]
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> arr1 = ['name','age','sex']
>>> val1 = ['Jone','20','male']
>>> dict(zip(arr1, val1))
{'age': '20', 'name': 'Jone', 'sex': 'male'}
```

Answer (score 1):

With python 2.7 onwards you could use dictionary comprehension

```
val = { k: v for k, v in zip(arr1, val1) }
```

Comment: @Macabeus, Yes, too, I meant... if you are not using something older than python 2.7 ;)

Comment: Thanks it's a good answer. I am accepting first answer as he answered first.

Answer (score 0):

```
val = {}
for i in range(len(arr1)):
    val[arr1[i]] = val1[i]
```